# Difference between WHITELIST and ALLOWLIST

Tags: firewall, cloudflare

I was being questioned about these 2 words while I do an IP allow/whitelist in some places like Cloudflare, what is the difference between these 2 words in the security context?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at the first sentence on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist

Comment: From Wikipedia: "A whitelist is a list or register of entities that are being provided a particular privilege, service, mobility, access or recognition."

That does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelist: A list or collection of people or entities that are known, trusted, or explicitly permitted

https://www.wordnik.com/words/whitelist

Allow list is a list of what to allow